# Firebase storage path to store images of a social post

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-storage, react-redux-firebase

I'm currently working on a social platform where users create posts similar to Facebook or Linkedin. So what I'm trying to achieve is, whenever user create a post they may upload images as part of the post and I want to store them in firebase storage but what I'm not clear is, what type of storage path I should choose from one of the below for uploading images.

Which option is right for user posts from the below?

1. Create unique storage path for every post of a user and upload
   respective post images there
2. Create unique storage path for every user and upload all user posts
   images there
3. Create a generic storage path for all users and upload all users
   posts images there

I'm using Firebase storage and database for this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no singular correct or best approach here, it all depends on your app's needs and use-cases.

I typically would use a folder structure with `/images/$uid/$postid`, for example because it makes it easy for me to delete all images for a specific user, as well as all images for a specific post. But as you can see from that description, that calls out two specific use-cases that might or might not be relevant for your app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing insights. Actually I instantly upload images when user is still on create post form. When user clicks save button then I will send post form data along with uploaded image urls and until this time I will not have postid. So how can I set path with postid in this case?